# Nav-items drift from the line on Bootstrap navbar

Tags: web-applications, blazor, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a Blazor web application with top bootstrap navigation bar, and I'm struggling to align all the items to one straight line.

This is NavMenu.razor code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">feonao</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler @NavButtonCssClass" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse"
                aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse @NavBarCssClass" id="navbarCollapse" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                        <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="music">
                        <span class="oi oi-media-play" aria-hidden="true"></span> Music
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="video">
                        <span class="oi oi-video" aria-hidden="true"></span> Video
                    </NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I get this result on the image. It looks the same on Edge, Chrome and Firefox.

[image: Navbar image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I remember that I had a similar problem. The note I left to myself was: delete line <link href="APPNAME.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> in _Layout.cshtml where APPNAME is name of your Blazor project.

Comment: I found this line only in index.html file under the <head> tag and deleted it, but it didn't do a trick unfortunately. PS: cleaned Edge cache, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: I will post it as an answer ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete line

```
<link href="APPNAME.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

in _Layout.cshtml or index.html (depending using which .NET version the project was created with). APPNAME is name of your Blazor project.